# ¿Qué significa "de complexión recia" en la descripción de Don Quijote

Tags: significado, adjetivos, literatura

> Frisaba la edad de nuestro hidalgo con los cincuenta años; era de complexión [recia](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/recio), seco de carnes, enjuto de rostro, gran madrugador y amigo de la caza.

¿Qué significa *de complexión recia* en la descripción del capítulo primero de *[El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2000/pg2000-images.html#id_1_primero)*?

Answer (score 3):

En este fragmento "**de complexión recia**" significa que el hidalgo en cuestión, a pesar de estar delgado, posee una estructura ósea y muscular robusta y fuerte, lo que significa que su apariencia física para la época era importante o no pasaba desapercibida. Además, se dice que es "seco de carnes", lo que significa que tiene poca grasa corporal y constitución delgada".

Esta descripción física del hidalgo sugiere que es una persona vigorosa y activa, capaz de realizar esfuerzos físicos con facilidad. Además, se menciona que es "gran madrugador", lo que sugiere una persona que está acostumbrada a levantarse temprano y empezar el día con energía.

Por último, se dice que es "amigo de la caza", lo que sugiere que es un apasionado de esta actividad y que disfruta pasando tiempo al aire libre. En general, esta descripción física y de personalidad del hidalgo encaja con la imagen de caballero idealista y valiente, dispuesto a luchar por la justicia y la verdad.

Para entender mejor ese concepto de "**complexión recia**", "**complexión fuerte**", podemos imaginarnos a la figura de los ciclistas actuales que ruedan por las carreteras o en las grandes competiciones como el Tour, el Giro o la Vuelta Ciclista a España, ellos están muy delgados pero a la vez poseen una gran fortaleza, capaz de recorrer cientos de kilómetros en bicicleta durante días. A pesar de su delgadez poseen una "***complexión recia, robusta o fuerte***", que le permite alcanzar y realizar tales proezas.

Por último indicar que la descripción física que se realiza de Don Quijote no es arbitraria y corresponde de manera no casual a las características que en la obra del doctor Huarte de San Juan, "**Examen de ingenios**", publicada en 1575, que se dan al hombre de temperamento "*caliente y seco*", que tiene muy pocas carnes, duras y ásperas... Es lo que diríamos hoy en día "una persona con mucho nervio", "persona de nervio" o "**puro nervio**". Personas coléricas y melancólicas, de gran temperamento y propensos a ciertas manías, notas ellas que encontramos en Don Quijote de la Mancha.